# How to subscribe to variable state change using knockout.js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, observable

Here is a basic knockout.js fiddle of what I want to achieve: https://jsfiddle.net/sr3wy17t/

It does what I want to do, but not exactly in a way I want.

For completeness I will repeat parts of the above fiddle code here:

In View I've got for-each which iterates over an observableArray of items:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: $root.availableItems">
 <div class="switchBox">
  <div class="switchName"><strong data-bind="text: '&nbsp;' + name()"></strong></div>
   <label class="Switch">
    <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: state">
   </label>
 </div>
```

It iterates over elements I have in my availableItems array:

```
self.availableItems([
new Item(1, "item1", state1, self.onItemStateChange),
new Item(2, "item2", state2, self.onItemStateChange),
new Item(3, "item3", state3, self.onItemStateChange)
]);
```

as you can see, I also have a function in which i initialize each of those items with observables:

```
function Item(id, name, state, onChange) {
  var self = this;

  self.id = ko.observable(id);
  self.name = ko.observable(name);
  self.state = ko.observable(state);

  self.state.subscribe(function(newValue) {
    onChange(self, newValue);
  });
}
```

Each of the items in an array has state variables (state1, state2, state3), which are boolean and they control which chekbox is checked and which one is not. They are (for the sake of this example) set at the beggining of ViewModel:

```
var state1 = true;
var state2 = false;
var state3 = false;
```

In reality state1, state2 and state3 are mapped from server. What I want to achieve, is after I initialize my items with starting state values, I want them to be subscribed on every change of state1, state2 and state3, so that checkbox is checked or not checked, depending on the recieved value from the server.

Currently the code in the fiddle achieves state change by accessing availableItems array like this:

```
    setInterval(()=>{
    var itemNoThatChanged=Math.floor(Math.random()*3);
    var newState=Math.random()>0.5;
   self.availableItems()[itemNoThatChanged].state(newState)
    },1000)
```

The issue here, is that it's not the change in state1 or state2 or state3 that is causing the change, but rather direct access to array of availableItems....

How can I change this code, so that the change of state1, state2 and state3 causes the above behavior like in fiddle?

I need to do this with as least changes to existing code approach as possible, since it affects a lot of other stuff in the original code.

Is this possible to do, and if yes, can someone please explain how to code this in knockout.js?

Answer (score 1):

Since you prefer a minimal change to your existing code;
declare your `state1`,  `state2` and `state3` variables as observables.

```
var state1 = ko.observable(true);
var state2 = ko.observable(false);
var state3 = ko.observable(false);
```

Adjust your `Item` to accept and use these as-is instead of setting up an observable itself.

```
function Item(id, name, state, onChange) {
    var self = this;

    self.id = ko.observable(id);
    self.name = ko.observable(name);
    self.state = state;

    self.state.subscribe(function(newValue) {
        onChange(self, newValue);
  });
}
```

---

The runnable example below, shows that a value change of the `state1` (observable) variable (triggered from the timer callback) also affects the checkbox, without any `array` access.

---

```js
function Item(id, name, state, onChange) {
  var self = this;

  self.id = ko.observable(id);
  self.name = ko.observable(name);
  self.state = state;

  self.state.subscribe(function(newValue) {
    onChange(self, newValue);
  });
}

function ViewModel() {
  var self = this;
  
  var state1 = ko.observable(true);
  var state2 = ko.observable(false);
  var state3 = ko.observable(false);

  self.availableItems = ko.observableArray([]);
  self.activeItemss = ko.computed(function() {
    return self.availableItems().filter(function(item) {
      return item.state();
    });
  });
  
    self.onItemStateChange = function(item, newValue) {
    console.log("State change event: " + item.name() + " (" + newValue + ")");
  };


  self.init = function() {
    self.availableItems([
      new Item(1, "item1", state1, self.onItemStateChange),
      new Item(2, "item2", state2, self.onItemStateChange),
      new Item(3, "item3", state3, self.onItemStateChange)
    ]);
    setInterval(()=>{
      // Simulate a change of state1
        state1(!state1());
      }, 1000);
  };
 }


var viewModel = new ViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
viewModel.init();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div data-bind="foreach: $root.availableItems">
  <div class="switchBox">
    <div class="switchName"><strong data-bind="text: '&nbsp;' + name()"></strong></div>
      <label class="Switch">
        <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: state">
      </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: pfx, thank you very much for your answer. This was what I was looking for. Only one questions....Is it possible to use this same approach if state1, state2 and state3 are variables mapped usping ko.mapping.fromJS mapping? Should I also change something else in that case?

Comment: @johndoe My first thought is that it should work as-is, since the ko.mapping utility just sets up observables (here: state1, 2 and 3) ... _but I don't use ko.mapping enough to give a 100% guarantee._

Comment: Tried the above. Fails with this error: Uncaught TypeError: self.state.subscribe is not a function

Comment: I guess better question would be this one: How to code this so taht checkbox can be control manually, and using a state variable recieved from server side....